# How to join 3 tables using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, model, eloquent, relation

How can I apply this query in laravel 5?
I have 3 table, Post, Profile, Comments

```
Post{id,title,body,user_id}
profile{user_id,last_name,first_name}
comments{comments,user_id,post_id}
```

I want to get this kind of structure:

`post_id  title post  last_name  first_name`

*and below are the comments*

`comments  last_name   fist_name`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

//post model

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comments', 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

//comments model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile', 'user_id');
}
```

//profile model

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comments');
}
```

and i call it in the controller using:

```
$posts = Posts::with('userProfile','comments', 'comments.user')->get();
```

Then it works:)
Thank you for some help and idea :)

Comment: Will this not be making three different database queries for each of the posts item in the background? Is this an optimal solution that is worth following?

Comment: @Lize What if I want to block users? Where I am maintaining tables 1. block_users 2.users 3.posts/videos

Answer (score -2):

If you need JUST those columns, you have to do something like this:

```
$users = DB::table('comments')
        ->join('profile', 'comments.user_id', '=', 'profile.user_id')
        ->select('comments.comments', 'profile.last_name', 'profile.first_name')
        ->get();
```

Anyway, I'd recommend using relations in your models if you are using the data in different places (or different structures).

P.S:

```
post_id  post  last_name  first_name
```

There's no "post" field in any table, do you need the post title?